# Is it possible to autoload dd() and or other dev tools at the IDE level not project

Tags: php, phpstorm, var-dump, psr-4, scratch-file

I was working in a scratch file and tried to use a non native function (muscle memory) and of cause it threw an error

`The PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd() in .../.scratch.php`

What I wanted to know is can I make [dd()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) for example available globally across all projects/scratch files without having to autoload it myself.

Essentially you would set a PSR-4 autoload path or directory to include.

After exploring the settings I didn't come up with a way of doing it so this is what I did instead.

```bash
composer global require --dev symfony/var-dumper
```

```php
<?php
include $_SERVER['APPDATA']. '/Composer/vendor/autoload.php';
$var = '';
dd($var);
```

Comment: The IDE (PhpStorm in this case) will NOT add such a custom code or you. It has no such options. BUT you can do it in your PHP. Just configure `auto_prepend_file` in your php.ini and see the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: In case of PhpStorm, you can pass such params to your PHP Interpreter or maybe even Run/Debug Configuration (need to check it first). As you know, you can also pass config params directly to PHP executable via command line parameters ( `-d` -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php )

Answer (score 0):

I just complete the answer above

To use 'vendor' projects and components in your phpstorm scratch file
include the file `vendor/autoload.php`
and for the example to check a Symfony component... :

```
require '/path/to/my/project/app/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Intl\Currencies;

\Locale::setDefault('sv');
$res = Currencies::getSymbol('SEK');
print_r($res);
```